# How to embed a plot drawn by Mathematica into a webpage

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, webmathematica

In this webpage for Calculus, [page](https://calculuswithjulia.github.io/integral_vector_calculus/div_grad_curl.html#7cd8de35-e519-4e1f-b380-35e8a66c7bb7)

the author presented graphs of surfaces in 3D so that we can interact with (rotating, zooming).

My question: can we create a graph using Mathematica and then embed it to a webpage with the same effect?

Thanks.

Comment: In the old days, when browsers still supported plugins, we used to use [LiveGraphics3D](http://wwwvis.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/~kraus/LiveGraphics3D/). Now, there is the [Wolfram Notebook Embedder](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/), which has the cost of eating up Cloud credits with each use.

Comment: So, that is, there is no way to embed a simple graph on a web platform for free anymore??? So sad. I 've looked up that Wordpress also asks for a subscription if we want to add Mathematica plugin into.

Comment: This is still possible if you have a Mathematica Online subscription and you use CloudDeploy. It's possible to include the result in an iframe to embed in a web page. I'm sure there are more sophisticated solutions also.

Comment: @Texas Tks, so we need to pay for it.

Comment: @Binjiu Sort of. There used to be more solutions for embedding CDFs into web pages, but this has changed because modern browsers no longer support the APIs necessary to run them. Additionally, if my memory serves, all versions of Mathematica come with a 'Cloud Basic' account that gives you a certain amount of cloud credits per month. Depending on the level of use or interaction that you anticipate for your shared graph, this may be enough for your application. It's worth looking into and playing with.